# hover and unhover goes into infinite loop

Tags: css, css-transitions

The code : http://jsfiddle.net/Gwx6E/

When you mouse over the div, and when the div boundary reaches the cursor the normal styles of the class `.a` are applied.
Making it to move under the cursor, which triggers the hover. This goes into the infinite loop.
Is there any way to slove this problem, with css3 alone ?

Comment: Not with only CSS3. Because you are moving the div so it's out of hover state, then it drops back into hover state, causing it to transition again. You'll need javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's the desired behavior (however there are the differences in some browsers: not everyone updates the hover state without the cursor's moving).

You can try to change the way your code is: add a wrapper and trigger the hover on it, so only the child block would move, but the hover would still be on the parent.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/Gwx6E/1/

Another way is to use the pseudo-element, that would be positioned over the screen so the hover would be always on the element when it would animate, here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/Gwx6E/2/ — however the drawback is that you could't de-hover this block until there won't be any blocks with bigger `z-index` that would be positioned in places where you'd like to unhover the block.